# What is the difference between NtFsControlFile() and DeviceIoControl() functions?

Tags: winapi

Are there any places where one is preferable to another? Is there a performance impact to using one over the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Alex K.: Small remark: `NtFsControlFile` is documented in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff566462(v=VS.85).aspx. Kernel mode application should use `ZwFsControlFile` function and user mode application can use `NtFsControlFile`.

@vedang: From you question I would assume that you don't a developer of kernel mode driver. So I will strictly recommend you to use **only** `DeviceIoControl` to send `FSCTL_XXX` codes http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364230(v=VS.85).aspx.

Only if you plan to write an application which don't use Win32 subsystem and use NT native subsystem only like a small checkdisk application or disk defragmentation application which run at the beginning of the windows start (see session manager registry key) than you will have advantage in using of `NtFsControlFile`. In all cases of usual work you should use only `DeviceIoControl`.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea about implementation, but `NtFsControlFile` is an undocumented kernel internal and it's use comes with the risk that it will disappear/change implementation at some point in the future, whereas `DeviceIoControl` is part of the public Win32 API.